# SMTP mail code is working fine in Android ICS but not in Gingerbread?

Tags: java, android, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I have written a code to send mail through SMTP, The mail is sent from android ICS devices, but from Gingerbread device mail is not sent.
Can anyone go through the code and help me...

Firstly I m calling sendmail() method of GMailOauthSender class.

```
class GMailOauthSender {

    private Session session;

    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port,
            String userEmail, String oauthToken, boolean debug)
            throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;
        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

        byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1",
                userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        return transport;
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
            String user, String oauthToken, String recipients, String cc) {
        try {
            spinner = ProgressDialog.show(FeedbackActivity.this, "",
                    getResources().getString(R.string.sending_mail), false, true);
            new SendMailTask().execute(subject, body, user, oauthToken,
                    recipients, cc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("exception inside send mail method", e.toString());
        }

    }

    class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String subject = (String) params[0];
            String body = (String) params[1];
            String user = (String) params[2];
            String oauthToken = (String) params[3];
            String recipients = (String) params[4];
            String cc = (String) params[5];
            try {
                SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp(
                        "smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, oauthToken, false);
                for(int i = 0; i< attachedFiles.size(); i++){
                    File file = new File(attachedFiles.get(i).getFilePath());
                    addAttachment(multipart, file);
                }
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
                message.setSubject(subject);

                MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                mbp1.setText(body + "\nThanks\n"+user+"\n\n"+getResources().getString(R.string.signature_text));
                multipart.addBodyPart(mbp1);


                message.setContent(multipart);
                if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0){
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
                }else{
                    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            new InternetAddress(recipients));
                }
                if(cc != null && cc.length() >0){
                    if (cc.indexOf(',') > 0){
                        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                                InternetAddress.parse(cc));
                    }else{
                        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                                new InternetAddress(cc));
                    }   

                }
                smtpTransport.sendMessage(message,
                        message.getAllRecipients());
                spinner.dismiss();
                finish();
                return new Object[] { smtpTransport, message };
            } catch (Exception e) {
                spinner.dismiss();
                finish();

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result != null){
            Toast.makeText(FeedbackActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.mail_sent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(FeedbackActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.mail_not_sent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its throwing javax.mail.messagingexception 334

Comment: Hi Neeraj, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes, It's working fine on ICS and Jellybean devices.

Comment: Neeraj, would you please share your code and what you fixed?

Comment: @Rohan Above code is working fine for ICS and above versions, but not for lower version.